# How to get name after login() function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I need to get `name` after user logged in via social network. But `console.log(name)` returns `undefined`. Why?

```
login() {
        var that = this;    
        var vk = {
            data: { user: { first_name: '', last_name: '', id: null } },
            init: new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                VK.init({ apiId: 6480684 });
                load();

                function load() {
                    VK.Auth.login(authInfo);

                    function authInfo(response) {
                        if (response.session) {
                            vk.data.user = response.session.user;
                            resolve();
                        } else {
                            reject();
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        async function data() {
            await vk.init;
            console.log('vk login');
            that.name = vk.data.user.first_name + ' ' + vk.data.user.last_name;
            that.id = vk.data.user.id;
            that.db.object('users/' + vk.data.user.id).set({
                id: vk.data.user.id,
                displayName: that.name
            });
        }
        data();
        console.log(this.name);
    }
```

After this function user added to database, but name is undefined.

Comment: What is the output of the vk.data.user.firstname/lastname?

Comment: `console.log(this.name);` execute before `that.name = ...` you sohuld to `await data(); `

Comment: @Michael Thank you, now this console.log works. But if I want to use this variable from another component it returns undefined. I have this code:
`VK.Observer.subscribe('auth.login', response => {
   this.isLoggedIn = true;
   this.router.navigate(['']);
   console.log(this.login.name);
   this.afService.displayName = this.login.name;
  }); `
(login refurs to LoginComponent)
Can you help with it?

Comment: Your question does not contain enough data to properly answer this question, try open another question

Comment: ok, thanks, i'll post another question

Comment: @Michael My new question has been deleted as duplicate, so could you explain me please, why If I type `LoginComponent.name` instead of `that.name` I have error `Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a constant or a read-only property.`