# How to change class variables in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to change `name` and `id` after login() function. But this

```
that.name = vk.data.user.first_name + ' ' + vk.data.user.last_name;
that.id = vk.data.user.id;
```

creates local variables `name` and `id`. How can I change name and id of LoginComponent class?

Login component:

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFire } from '../shared';
import {
    AngularFireDatabase,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    FirebaseListObservable,
    FirebaseObjectObservable
} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class LoginComponent {
    public error: any;
    public name: string;
    public id: number;

    constructor(public afService: AngularFire, private router: Router, public db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

    async login() {
        var that = this;    
        var vk = {
            data: { user: { first_name: '', last_name: '', id: null } },
            appID: 6480684,
            init: new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                VK.init({ apiId: 6480684 });
                load();

                function load() {
                    VK.Auth.login(authInfo);

                    function authInfo(response) {
                        if (response.session) {
                            vk.data.user = response.session.user;
                            resolve();
                        } else {
                            reject();
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        async function data() {
            await vk.init;
            console.log('vk login');
            that.name = vk.data.user.first_name + ' ' + vk.data.user.last_name;
            that.id = vk.data.user.id;
            that.db.object('users/' + vk.data.user.id).set({
                id: that.id,
                displayName: that.name
            });
        }
        await data();
    }
```

Chat component:

```
import { Component, AfterViewChecked, ElementRef, ViewChild, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { LoginComponent } from '../../login/login.component';

import { AngularFire } from '../../shared';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css']
})
export class ChatComponent implements AfterViewChecked, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('scroller') private myScrollContainer: ElementRef;
  @Input() channelId;

  public messages: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  imageSrc: string;
  public newMessage: string;
  public newImage: any;

  constructor(public afService: AngularFire, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public login: LoginComponent) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.messages = this.afService.getMessages(this.channelId);
  }

        async sendMessage() {
            var name;
            if (this.afAuth.auth.currentUser !== null) {
                name = await this.afService.getDisplayName();
            } else {
                name = this.login.name;
                console.log(name);
            }
        this.afService.sendMessage(this.channelId, this.newMessage, name);
    this.newMessage = '';
  }
```

Comment: Use fat arrow operator `(=>)` instead of `function`, so that you don't need to use `that` instead of `this`.

Comment: How is `login()` being called?

Comment: @ConnorsFan from login.component.html after button click
`<div id="vk_api_transport"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="login()">Sing in using VK</button></div>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get name after login() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656652/how-to-get-name-after-login-function)

Comment: Should it be worth noting that your code has variables vk and VK which are not the same?  Have you run the code and checked the console for errors?

Comment: @AmitChigadani I've changed code to  `var data = async () => {
   await vk.init;
   console.log('vk login');
   this.name = vk.data.user.first_name + ' ' + vk.data.user.last_name;
   this.id = vk.data.user.id;
   this.db.object('users/' + vk.data.user.id).set({
    id: this.id,
    displayName: this.name
   });
  }
  await data();` but same result

Comment: @JeffryHouser It works with no errors. But I can't use name and id from another component. Also, if I type LoginComponent.name instead of that.name I have error `Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a constant or a read-only property.`

Comment: @ИванСидоров Can you show how you are trying to access the values in different components?

Comment: @AmitChigadani I have chat component with
`import { LoginComponent } from '../../login/login.component';`
....
`constructor(...public login: LoginComponent) {}` and function
`async sendMessage() {
  var name;
  if (this.afAuth.auth.currentUser !== null) {
   name = await this.afService.getDisplayName();
  } else {
   name = this.login.name;
   console.log(name);
  }`
Before login component @Injectable()

Comment: Please add all your code inside the question

Comment: @AmitChigadani I've changed question

Comment: You cannot inject a component inside another component. Instead you can share your component data to other component via some angular service. You will find number of posts to share data between components. Have a look at them. What you are doing is not correct.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Ok, I will try to do it via service, thank you Amit!